# What is B.N in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf'))
FROM BST AS B
ORDER BY N;
```

Here N and P are the column names where N is node and P is parent,BST is the name of table and the above query is to find node type of BST but i am not able to understand **what P=B.N mean**?

Comment: Local scope P, B.N from outer query.

Comment: @jarlh can you pls elaborate,i did not understand

Comment: he means ... you have your BST table 2 times ... once in the outer scope where it is aliased B ... and once in the local scope of your subquery where it has no alias ... P is column P of BST in the local scope

Comment: It checks if current node is parent to some other node. It does so by running a subquery from same table searching for nodes where P equals current node N.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me start by saing I really hope these are not the actual names you are using. If they are, do your future self a huge favor and replace them with readable names that actually describs the data the columns and tables holds.

That being said, `B.N` is the `N` column in the row of the outer query, since it's using `B` as an alias to the table name.

In the `where` clause of the sub query, you are comparing the value of `P` with the value of `N` from the main query. This subquery will run once for each row in the main query, so for each row you are getting the count of rows where `N` is a parent of some node.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
WHERE P=B.N
```

`P` is the "parent" column of `BST` of the inner most `SELECT` statement.

`B.N` refers to th e`N` ("node") column of the `BST` table referred in the **outer** `SELECT` statement.

The clause

```
FROM BST AS B
```

creates `B` as the alias for the outer `BST`.

Answer (score 0):

"From BST as B" defines that B to be used as variable for the table BST for this query and N has to be a column in that table so:

cell value of column N in table BST

Answer (score 0):

For any value in `column N` from `table B`, first find how many records does the `column P` has when the value in P equal to the one in N, if the total number is larger than 0, populate it as `Inner`, otherwise `Leaf`